# How to make this MySQL query execute faster?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
SELECT * FROM (`collection_series`) 
  JOIN `datadatexnumericy` ON 
    `collection_series`.`series_id` = `datadatexnumericy`.`series_id` 
  JOIN `saved_users_chart` ON `collection_series`.`collection_id` =
    `saved_users_chart`.`chart_id` 
 WHERE `saved_users_chart`.`chart_id` = '265' 
    AND `saved_users_chart`.`id` = '6' AND `datadatexnumericy`.`x` >= 
    '1973-09-30' AND `datadatexnumericy`.`x` <= '2014-06-30' AND 
    `datadatexnumericy`.`series_id` != '43538' 
    AND `datadatexnumericy`.`series_id` != '43541' 
    GROUP BY YEAR(datadatexnumericy.x)
```

This is my SQL query and result of this query I am getting from AJAX response this query is working fine but I am getting response slow a bit I think the problem is in my SQL query.

I want all matching records from `collection_series` and `datadatexnumericy` table and only matching row from `saved_users_chart` is there any possible way to optimize this query in more efficient way so that I can get ajax response faster.

Comment: How about pagination? in your query -> LIMIT 0,10 LIMIT 11,20 so on?

Comment: Without an idea of how many rows you have in these tables, and what indexes you have, and an explain plan, this is probably not possible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your query is already optimized. You should test the result of the query in an SQL server to see response time of SQL server and then compare with the time you actualy receive the response back from server.

If is not necesary to extract all the columns from each table, then manualy enter the column names instead of *. By doing this the response received from server will be certainly smaller, therefore it will be faster.